# How do I get my text / cursor back when running a byebug session with Rails and the server times out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, iterm2, byebug

I have a Rails (5.2.2.1) application on Ruby (2.6.2p47) with Puma as the local development server.

When I am debugging using Byebug I find that when the Puma thread times out and resets, the consecutive Byebug sessions don't display the text of the commands that I type.

My solution is to restart the Rails server which can take some time.

No text is displayed:

[image: there is no text being displayed when I type]

This seems like a pretty common issue but no one has posted the question here, so I'm adding it along with a solution that works for me:

Comment: Please don't use images for information that could be used to search or debug a problem. Forcing us to retype text only discourages those who want to help you.

Comment: @theTinMan I didn't use an image for information that could be used to search or debug a problem. The images are only for illustrative purposes. Did you read the question?

Answer (score 3):

I created an iTerm (on Mac OS) shortcut that sends

```
`stty sane`
```

to the terminal. (Backticks are important to send the command to the shell, not to the Byebug session).

[image]

If you're not using iTerm, you can just type in the command in backticks or configure whatever tool you're using to send the command.

I have a good workaround thanks to a [comment](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/issues/59) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

There is another workaround for this. Increase the byebug timeout

```
# config/puma.rb    
...
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
...
if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
  worker_timeout 3600
end
```